# Cannot run as "PyDev: Django" in Eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

When creating a new Django project in Eclipse I can run the server by running the project as "PyDev: Django" like in the following screenshot:

[image: Run As --> PyDev: Django]

I've recently forked a Django project from [GitHub](http://github.com), added it to Eclipse and set it as a Django project. The problem is that I don't have the option to run the project as "PyDev: Django" when trying to do so in Eclipse:

[image: Run As --> Run Configurations]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you fork a django project or a django app? A project has all the files necessary to run the dev server, but a django app must be installed into an existing project to run.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue after importing an existing project in Eclipse.

Here is how I solved it:

- set your directory to Django project using "PyDev" -> "set as Django project"
- use the same "PyDev" menu and set it "as a PyDev project".

The last command will configure the pydev nature of the project. You should now have the "PyDev: Django" and "Python unit-test" options to the "Run as" menu.